# Составление договора

Tags: грамматика

В договоре написано: "Индивидуальный предприниматель..., действующий на основании Свидетельства..." Как правильно склонять слово "действующий": от слова "предприниматель" или от фамилии предпринимателя?

Answer (score 1):

> "Индивидуальный предприниматель..., действующий на основании
>   Свидетельства..."

Если после слова "предприниматель" (там, где у Вас многоточие) стоит мужская фамилия, то проблем возникнуть не должно:

*Индивидуальный предприниматель Сидоров, действующий на основании
Свидетельства... - индивидуальным предпринимателем Сидоровым, действующим на основании Свидетельства... - об индивидуальном предпринимателе Сидорове, действующем на основании
Свидетельства...* - и так в любом падеже.

Но если гипотетический предприниматель - женщина...

> Трудности возникают при употреблении существительных, обозначающих лиц
>   по роду деятельности или по профессии.
>
> Существительные мужского рода, обозначающие лиц мужского и женского
>   пола типа врач, инженер, технолог, банкир, ассистент, менеджер,
>   коммерсант, как правило, согласуются с прилагательными в форме
>   мужского рода (т. е. по окончанию), а с глаголами - в форме мужского
>   или женского рода в зависимости от принадлежности лица к мужскому или
>   женскому полу (т. е. по значению).
>
> Например: Опытный адвокат Иванова выиграла процесс. - Опытный адвокат
>   Иванов выиграл процесс; Участковый врач Смирнова посетила больного. -
>   Участковый врач Смирнов посетил больного.

То же относится и к причастиям (синтаксически - определениям).

В нашем случае:

*Индивидуальн**ый** предприниматель Сидорова, действующая на основании Свидетельства...*

Ещё одна [цитата](http://rustest.edu.ru/rules/morf/sushest/3055/):

> Существительные врач, профессор, архитектор, депутат, экскурсовод,
>   автор и подобные, называющие лицо по профессии, роду деятельности,
>   относятся к мужскому роду. Однако они могут обозначать и лиц женского
>   пола.
>
> Согласование определений в этом случае подчиняется следующим правилам:
>
> 1) необособленное определение должно ставиться в форме мужского рода,
>   например: *На нашем участке появился молодой врач Сергеева. Новый
>   вариант статьи закона предложил молодой депутат Петрова;*
>
> 2) обособленное определение, стоящее после имени собственного,
>   должно ставиться в форме женского рода, например: *Профессор Петрова,
>   уже известная стажёрам, удачно прооперировала больного.*
>
> Сказуемое должно ставиться в форме женского рода, если:
>
> 1) в предложении есть имя собственное, стоящее перед сказуемым,
>   например: *Директор Сидорова получила премию. Экскурсовод Петрова
>   провела студентов по старей­шим улицам Москвы;*
>
> 2) форма сказуемого является единственным показателем того, что речь
>   идет о женщине, а пишущему важно это подчеркнуть, например: *Директор
>   школы оказалась хоро­шей матерью.*

Answer (score -1):

От слова "Предприниматель", но можно и фамилию принять во внимание.

Comment: Лучше принимать: нетрудно, а им приятно.